# In F#, how to break a list down into multiple subgroups and return all subgroups?

Tags: f#

(Newbie question). I have a database function in which I am downloading essentially an unordered set of records with the following record format (in C#):

```
public partial class view_rx
    {
        public int? rx_recid { get; set; }    
        public DateTime? trx { get; set; }    
        public string medname { get; set; }
        public string ssig { get; set; }
        public int disp { get; set; }
        public string form { get; set; }
        public int refills { get; set; }
        public DateTime? tstop { get; set; }
        public DateTime? tprinted { get; set; }
    }
```

All records will have either a trx or tstop time, or both.

How can these records be grouped by trx DATE or tstop DATE (when trx is null) in F#? That is, how can the returned database list be returned as multiple sub lists, with each list representing a single date?  All this in F#?  (I'm stumped on how to do groupings in F#).

(No code posted because I don't know where to start :( )

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried googling "F# group list"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin  Thanks. Knowing where to look is half the problem.

Comment: But that's literally what you asked! "How can these records be grouped by..."

Comment: @FyodorSoikin  True! But for some reason I was only getting C# answers -- which I'm trying to translate to F#.  Oh well.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Hmm...not having much luck. Seem to get bogged down on List.Collect. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you want is [`groupBy`](https://bradcollins.com/2015/11/13/f-friday-seq-groupby/). There are versions for each of the basic F# collection types (e.g. `List.groupBy`, `Seq.groupBy`, etc.).

Here's a quick example that does what you want:

```ml
// Simplified F# version of your record type
type view_rx =
    {
        rx_rec : Option<int>
        trx : Option<DateTime>
        tstop : Option<DateTime>
    }

// Group records by trx/tstop
let records = getRecords ()
let groups =
    records
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun record ->
            record.trx
                |> Option.orElse record.tstop)

// Display the results
for (date, records) in groups do
    printfn ""
    printfn "%A" date
    for record in records do
        printfn "   %A" record.rx_rec
```

With some made-up data:

```ml
let records =
    [|
        {
            rx_rec = Some 1
            trx = "7/1/2021" |> DateTime.Parse |> Some
            tstop = None
        }
        {
            rx_rec = Some 2
            trx = None
            tstop = "7/1/2021" |> DateTime.Parse |> Some
        }
        {
            rx_rec = Some 3
            trx = "7/2/2021" |> DateTime.Parse |> Some
            tstop = None
        }
        {
            rx_rec = Some 4
            trx = None
            tstop = "7/2/2021" |> DateTime.Parse |> Some
        }
    |]
```

Output is:

```
Some 7/1/2021 12:00:00 AM
   Some 1
   Some 2

Some 7/2/2021 12:00:00 AM
   Some 3
   Some 4
```

Comment: Wow! This is so much better (and different) then the junk I was coming up with. Thanks! Option.orElse was unknown to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlanWayne The `Option` module is full of useful functions like that. You can also achieve the same thing with pattern matching if you prefer.